# Series name dxchart devextreme

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, devexpress

Actualmente trabajo con ASP.NET y devextreme component. Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo darle nombre a mis "series" de la gráfica desde el código C#? Devextreme muestra como hacerlo desde el lado del cliente pero no desde el lado del servidor.

Mi ejemplo de proyecto es muy similar al ejemplo tomado en esta página: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4470 )

Los argumentos y los valores funcionan bien, pero no las series.

Éste es mi código, pero no funciona:

Jscript:

```
$(function () {



  $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
    dataSource: chartData,


    commonSeriesSettings: {
        type: "line",

        hoverMode: "allArgumentPoints",
        selectionMode: "allArgumentPoints",
        label: {
            visible: false,

        },


    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        format: "fixedPoint",
        precision: 2,

        customizeText: function () {
            return this.valueText + ' Q';
        }

    },


    series: [

        { argumentField: 'argumento1', valueField: 'valor1', name: 'Ano_A', color: 'DarkSeaGreen' },
        { argumentField: 'argumento2', valueField: 'valor2', name: 'Ano_B', color: 'LightBlue' },

    ],

    argumentAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,

    },

    legend: {
        horizontalAlignment: 'center'
    }



});   });
```

Datahelper C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Dashboard.ks.Dashboard.ks;


public class DataHelper
{


public DataHelper()
{
    Dashboard.Query.Sale.Instance.ListSaleDaily = Dashboard.Query.Sale.LevelOne.UnionOrderSale();


}

public IEnumerable GetItemsQ()
{

    List<KBInfo> kbItems = new List<KBInfo>();


    foreach (var day in inicio.ListA)
    {

        kbItems.Add(new KBInfo()
        {
            argumento1 = (day.Day),
            valor1 = (day.Qtysold),
           // Ano_A=(inicio.Ano),

            Ano_A = 2016,

        });
    }

    foreach (var day in inicio.ListB)
    {
        kbItems.Add(new KBInfo()
        {
            argumento2 = (day.Day),
            valor2 = (day.Qtysold),
           // Ano_B = (inicio.Ano - 1),
            Ano_B = 2015,


        });
    }


    return kbItems;
}



}

public class KBInfo
{
public int argumento1 { get; set; }
public int argumento2 { get; set; }
public decimal valor1 { get; set; }
public decimal valor2 { get; set; }
public int Ano_A { get; set; }
public int Ano_B { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Puedes hacer la traducción al Español por favor

Comment: Actualmente trabajo con ASP.NET y devextreme component. mi pregunta es: Como puedo darle nombre a mis "series" de la gráfica desde el código C#? Devextreme muestra como hacerlo desde el lado del cliente pero no desde el lado del servidor. Mi ejemplo de proyecto es muy similar al ejemplo tomado en esta página:  https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4470

Comment: Hola noel, el tema es que el sitio es solo para preguntas en español, he visto que has preguntado antes en español. Para mantener un cierto orden del sitio podrias traducir la pregunta por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inicialmente desconocía el código Jquery. La respuesta era muy sencilla.

Solo cambiar el string de la serie.

Donde dice valor1 y valor2 ahora sutituye con cualquier nombre que quieras llamar a la variable.

```
series: [

    { argumentField: 'argumento1', valueField: 'NUEVO VALOR 1', name: 'Ano_A', color: 'DarkSeaGreen' },
    { argumentField: 'argumento2', valueField: 'NUEVO VALOR 1', name: 'Ano_B', color: 'LightBlue' },

],
```